Making license as permissive as possible except for specific users?
Lets say I am petty and want to make a license that is as permissive as possible (unrestricted use, modification, distribution, no need for attribution etc.) EXCEPT I don't want a specific legal entitiy (e.g. my former employer) to be able to use my code for any commercial purpose.

Is that legally possible at all?
Is there maybe some notable precedence for this?
Which existing license would be most suitable to be amended for such a purpose?


I would vote to close as the resulting license would not be accepted as open source.

@doneal24 Does it say in the rules of this substack that "open source" specifically means what OSI says open source means? There is an SSPL tag which wouldn't really make sense if that were the case.

This site here uses the OSI definition of Open Source, as you can see here: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

It's also completely pointless, because as an unnamed third party I can take your code on those non-copyleft permissive terms then relicense it to the named entity without the restriction.

@Peter FYI, the questions around the SSPL are heavily based in a FLOSS context, along the lines of either "is it GPL compatible? what sorts of adjacent uses cause copyleft issues?" or "in what ways is SSPL non-free? what motivated them to move away from free licensing terms?" rather than mechanical questions about how to apply it or comply with it (which you correctly suggest would be off-topic)
